# Blazor Rest Api call using httpClient.GetJsonAsync Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, blazor, rest, asp.net-blazor

I am trying to make a call to a Rest API from Blazor Server Application using the following call to get a list of projects. The API returns correctly but it cannot map to the Project Object because the JSON for the projects is nested under a results property.

This is the call I am making

```
var projects = await httpClient.GetJsonAsync<Project[]>("projects");
```

And this is what the response from the API call looks like.

```
{
  "message": "GET Request successful.",
  "isError": false,
  "result": [
    {
      "projectCode": "PRJ-1996",
      "businessAssociateID": "BA000000000002",
      "contractStartDate": "11/19/2020 8:37:17 AM",
      "contractEndDate": "11/19/2020 8:37:17 AM",
      "contractStatus": "Active",
      "createdBy": "system",
      "createdDate": "2020-11-19T08:37:17.37",
      "active": true
    },
    {
      "projectCode": "PRJ-1997",
      "businessAssociateID": "BA000000000002",
      "contractStartDate": "11/19/2020 8:37:17 AM",
      "contractEndDate": "11/19/2020 8:37:17 AM",
      "contractStatus": "Active",
      "createdBy": "system",
      "createdDate": "2020-11-19T08:37:17.37",
      "active": true
    },
    {
      "projectCode": "PRJ-1998",
      "businessAssociateID": "BA000000000002",
      "contractStartDate": "11/19/2020 8:37:17 AM",
      "contractEndDate": "11/19/2020 8:37:17 AM",
      "contractStatus": "Active",
      "createdBy": "system",
      "createdDate": "2020-11-19T08:37:17.37",
      "active": true
    },
    {
  ]
}
```

How can I use the GetJsonAsync function to map to the Projects list. All the examples that I have seen only return the array of objects without the response messages.

This is the error I receive on the call. The routes are correct to the API call as well as that was already tested.

```
JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to Web.Data.Project[]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and easy way out would be

```
class Response
{
   public string  Message { get; set; }
   public bool  IsError { get; set; }
   public Project[] Result { get; set; }
}
```

This lets you have a look at IsError and Message too.